# Indexing a Python Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

I am attempting to analyse high school attendance and behaviour data. I have a raw excel data sheet as shown in the image.
[image]

I get lost with how to index it. Essentially the first three columns should be "Student Name, Class and Percent Attendance". Then all subsequent columns are a 2 level index, the first of which is "date" and the sub-index "period name".

How can I delete the appropriate rows and columns to achieve this and the index be correct. Many thanks

Graham

I don't really know what to try? Historically I have "hard-wired" what I want into a Python Array but I really want to become more proficient with dataframes and see this as a good project to have a go upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to load the spreadsheet as it is, then *post-process* it :

```
raw = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")

idx_names = ["Student Name", "Class", "Percent Attendance"]
left = raw.iloc[2:, :3].set_axis(idx_names, axis=1)

col_mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(raw.iloc[:2, 3:].ffill(axis=1).to_numpy())
right = raw.iloc[2:, 3:]

df = (pd.concat([left, right], axis=1)
        .set_index(idx_names).set_axis(col_mux, axis=1))
```

Output :

```
# df.index.nlevels # 2
# df.columns.nlevels # 3

print(df)

                                      19/9/2023                         20/9/2023            
                                             AM PM   P1 P2 P3   P4   P5        AM PM P1 P2 P3
Student Name Class Percent Attendance                                                        
Student A    7M    100%                       /  \    /  /  /  NaN    /         /  \  /  /  /
Student B    12H   100%                       /  \  NaN  /  N  NaN  NaN         /  \  /  /  /
Student C    8R    100%                       /  \    /  /  /  NaN  NaN         /  \  /  /  /

[3 rows x 12 columns]
```